# Rails: how to create a migration that add 'using: :btree' to foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models
father has_many sons
son belongs_to father

Normally, this piece of code

```
def change
    add_reference :sons, :father, index: true
end
```

it will generate

```
add_index "sons", ["father_id"], name: "index_sons_on_father_id"
```

Now, I want it generate

```
add_index "sons", ["father_id"], name: "index_sons_on_father_id", using: :btree
```

How to write the migration?

Answer (score 0):

you just check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/31rd8d/rails_foreign_key_issue_unable_to_migrate/)

you can do look like this.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150321171548) do
  create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "hashtags"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "author_id",    limit: 4
    t.string   "title",        limit: 255
    t.string   "bannerurl",    limit: 255
    t.string   "thumbnailurl", limit: 255
    t.text     "content",      limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  add_index "articles", ["author_id"], name: "index_articles_on_author_id", using: :btree
end
```